# Dropdown hover enable/disable on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm wanting the dropdown to open on hover, only if the window is larger than 767px. I'm trying to call a function on page load and on window resize with the a width size condition. The enableHover() function only works on page load and not on window resize.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/gabe1331/pen/mBjXNZ)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">dropdown link</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">dropdown link</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">dropdown link</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //call dropdown hover and on load & resize
    $( window ).resize(function() {
        enableHover();
    });
    enableHover();
});

//emable hover when window > 767px 
function enableHover() {
   if ($(window).width() > 767) {
      $('nav.navbar li.dropdown').hover(function() {
         $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
       }, function() {
         $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
         });
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unbind the hover action.  Your `.resize` function is working but there is nothing removing the hover action from the dropdown.  Add something like:

```
function enableHover() {
    if ($(window).width() > 767) {
        $('nav.navbar li.dropdown').hover(function() {
              $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
            }, function() {
              $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
        });
    } else {
        $('nav.navbar li.dropdown').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave')
    }
}
```

And here is a working codepen:

https://codepen.io/egerrard/pen/qPyYwR

Or an even easier solution would be to just use css:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0; 
 }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) { 
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu
    display: none;
    margin-top: auto; 
}
```

See it in action here:

https://codepen.io/egerrard/pen/OxwwKm

Comment: After messing with your codepin, it seems to only work part of the time. Other times, it wouldn't open on click or it would open on hover. Not sure if this is a robust solution.

Comment: @gabe1331 You are correct, updated answer with another solution.